Normal subgroups of (2,4,4) triangle group and thier defining relations of automorphism group
Q.1 I want to find all the normal subgroups of a triangle group (2,4,4) using LowIndexNormalSubgroups (LINS) package in GAP. Here is my code:
Q.2 After obtaining all the normal subgroups how I can obtain the Defining relations for automorphism group.?
I wrote this code in GAP
LoadPackage("LINS");

FG := FreeGroup("a", "b", "c");

a := FG.1; b := FG.2; c := FG.3;

rels := [a^2, b^2, c^2, (a*b)^2, (b*c)^4, (c*a)^4];

triangleGroup := FG / rels;

subgroups := LowIndexNormalSubs(triangleGroup, 16);

structureDescriptions := List(subgroups, StructureDescription);

Print("Structure descriptions of normal subgroups with index up to 16:\n");
Print(structureDescriptions, "\n");

On running of this code, I am constantly getting this error "#I  Coset table calculation failed -- trying with bigger table limit" though it is displaying all the normal subgroups.
